# Value increment of textbox in C#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 textbox and 1 button textbox1,textbox2 and 1 increment button.Both textbox is initialize by 1.If i will click on textbox1 and then click on incr button the value belongs to textbox1 will be increase only.And whenever i will click on textbox2 and again i will click on incr button only textbox2 value will be increment.
How will i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a windows form application and paste this code on form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox(), textbox2 = new TextBox();
        Button button1 = new Button();
        int FocusedTextBox = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

            textbox1.Text = textbox2.Text = "1";
            textbox1.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            textbox2.Location = new Point(100, 140);
            button1.Location = new Point(100, 180);

            textbox1.Click += new EventHandler(textbox1_Click);
            textbox2.Click += new EventHandler(textbox2_Click);
            textbox1.ReadOnly = true;
            textbox2.ReadOnly = true;

            this.Controls.Add(textbox1);
            this.Controls.Add(textbox2);
            this.Controls.Add(button1);
        }

        void textbox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FocusedTextBox = 2;
        }

        void textbox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FocusedTextBox = 1;
        }

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FocusedTextBox ==1)
                textbox1.Text = (int.Parse(textbox1.Text) + 1).ToString();
            else if (FocusedTextBox == 2)
                textbox2.Text = (int.Parse(textbox2.Text) + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am very new in >net environment How will i set textbox2_Click function in my class.How this function will be call if i will click on textbox2.I am not getting this function suggestion in my class

Comment: you should read more about visual programing, windows forms, event based applications and much more. I suggest you instead of asking question here read some books or online C# refrences

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say whether you were in WinForms or in WPF, so I won't show any code.

Have a field `TextBox activeTextBox` in your class. In the GotFocus events of each textbox, set activeTextBox = this text box. In the button click, convert activeTextBox's text to an integer, add one, and convert back to string and set the text back.

**Edit**:

`activeTextBox` is a field you will need to set up, the designer won't make it for you. If you set the `GotFocus` event of `textBox1` set `activeTextBox = textBox1`, and similar for `textBox2`, then `activeTextBox` will always have the 'current' text box. Then in the button's click event, you can do whatever you need to do on `activeTextBox`. You shouldn't need to access `textBox1` or `textBox2` from the button click handler at all.

Comment: textBox1.Focused is always returing False.

Comment: TextBox activeTextBox  i did not get this one in my class.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done on the client side using javascript. On focus of textbox1 update a hiddenfield value. similarly for the textbox2. then on button click, based on hidden f

Answer (score 0):

```
private int pickedbox = 0

[...]

private void textBox1_Enter(...)
{
    pickedbox = 0;
}

private void textBox2_Enter(...)
{
    pickedbox = 1;
}

private void button1_Click(...)
{
    switch(pickedbox)
    {
        case 0:
            textBox1.Text = int.Parse(textBox1.Text)++;
            break;
        case 1:
            textBox2.Text = int.Parse(textBox2.Text)++;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: textBox1_Enter is this predefined function ? I am not getting this properties in VS2005 .net.Will it call automatically ?

Comment: Not sure about 2005 - just check the events for something that fires in situations you'd like the "active" text box to switch (e.g. Click). It doesn't have to be "Enter". It won't be called just because the method is there. You'll have to add it to the form's events.

Answer (score 0):

if (textBox1.Focused)
            {
                textBox1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + 1) + "";

```
        }
        else if (textBox2.Focused)
        {
            textBox2.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) + 1) + "";

        }

        else if (textBox3.Focused)
        {
            textBox3.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + 1) + "";

        }
```

But ".Focused" is always returing False.
Why ?

Comment: Because the button is focused (assuming that this is in a button click)

Comment: Bcoz, when you click on button the focus changes to that button which you have clicked....